# Spark: Intersection between Key-Value pair and Key RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two RDDs; `rdd1 = RDD[(String, Array[String])]` and `rdd2 = RDD[String]`.
I want to remove all rdd1's where the Key is not found in rdd2.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do inner join and select only rdd1 values

Answer (score 1):

You can make an inner join but first you have to make the second RDD be pair rdd.

```
val rdd1: RDD[(String, Array[String])] = ???
val rdd2: RDD[String] = ???
val asPairRdd: RDD[(String, Unit)] = rdd2.map(s => (s, ()))
val res: RDD[(String, Array[String])] = rdd1.join(asPairRdd).map{
   case (k, (v, dummy)) => (k, v)
}
```